# How to get 2 CMD windows to 'talk' to each other?

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, ipc

I am probably missing the right vocabulary to talk about this problem more succinctly so excuse me if I'm a little wordy here. Under Windows 10 I have a program that runs inside a CMD command prompt It's an executable called OpenSim and it has it's own extensive command set, including 'shutdown', which initiates a graceful termination of the processes therein, closes SQL connections etc, then finally closes the CMD command window. I also have a CMD .bat file that is activated by my UPS when the power goes down that will of course open it's own window, and then does some housekeeping before closing down the hardware. One thing I want the .bat file to do is to somehow insert a 'shutdown'command into the other window's process. Is that possible? If so, how? Please assume I am a total newbie at this and you won't go far wrong. Thank you.

> **EDIT** It looks like creating a file to flag the closedown event taking place is the only (and I guess rather primitive) way to do this. So, building on what others have said in stackoverflow, I have the following now. When I run it to test it waits - it doesn't. It runs right through to the end, running 'shutdown', even though the UPSFLAG.TXT file does not exist. What's going wrong?

```
echo Waiting for UPS Power Down Signal.
echo =================================
@ECHO OFF
SET LookForFile="C:\Opensim OSGrid\UPSFLAG.TXT"

:CheckForFile
IF EXIST %LookForFile% GOTO FoundIt

REM If we get here, the file is not found.

REM Wait 10 seconds and then recheck.
REM If no delay is needed, comment/remove the timeout line.
TIMEOUT /T 10 >nul

GOTO CheckForFile


:FoundIt
ECHO Found: %LookForFile%
rem Tidy up
del "C:\Opensim OSGrid\UPSFLAG.TXT"
shutdown
```

Comment: not with pure batch. (there is no "communication" implemented. Usually communication between different instances is done by a file). Some other languages have commands to emulate keystrokes.

Comment: it's not a DOS command prompt. [Command Prompt and MS-DOS the not the same thing](https://superuser.com/q/451432/241386). cmd.exe runs pure win32 applications so they can communicate just like any win32 apps

Comment: "so they can communicate just like any win32 apps" - so, how would i do it? And if it helps to know, these 2 would be the only command prompt' windows open at the time.

Comment: Can you make use of the [`waitfor` command](http://ss64.com/nt/waitfor.html)?

Comment: waitfor: I don't know the command but just tested it (I am using Windows 10) and it recognised it to the extent it told me I had it's syntax incorrect, so a good sign. How might this help?

Comment: yes it can be done. You would need to write to a file. The second batch file would need to read from file in a loop and once it finds the shutdown command, it initiates it.

Comment: Try `GOTO :CheckForFile` (with the colon)

Comment: `SET LookForFile="C:\Opensim OSGrid\UPSFLAG.TXT"`this is wrong. it adds the texts with the quotes. rather do `SET "LookForFile=C:\Opensim OSGrid\UPSFLAG.TXT"`

Comment: @PhilipKelley no need to use goto with the colon.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding double quote after the = will save your variable as that `"C:\Opensim OSGrid\UPSFLAG.TXT"` which you do not want. rather you want to store it as `C:\Opensim OSGrid\UPSFLAG.TXT` so move the quote to before lookforfile.

Also, you created a variable for the file, so you might as well use it in the delete.

Finally, as a safety measure, always put an exit after a goto. That will ensure the system exists should there be a problem in the script and you can make sure you do not delete files or shutdown the system when it was not planned for.

```
echo Waiting for UPS Power Down Signal.
echo =================================
@ECHO OFF
SET "LookForFile=C:\Opensim OSGrid\UPSFLAG.TXT"

:CheckForFile
IF EXIST "%LookForFile%" GOTO FoundIt

REM If we get here, the file is not found.

REM Wait 10 seconds and then recheck.
REM If no delay is needed, comment/remove the timeout line.
TIMEOUT /T 10 >nul

GOTO CheckForFile
exit

:FoundIt
ECHO Found: %LookForFile%
rem Tidy up
del "%LookForFile"
shutdown
```

Comment: You have a single double-quote after the path is specified. Does that need an opener or should that be removed completely - if so, how will it cope with the 'space' character in the path?

Comment: the opener is before the variable name. "LookForFile=C:\Opensim OSGrid\UPSFLAG.TXT"

Comment: So it is! Your slight-of-hand dazzled me there. Haha! Thank you Gerhard.

Comment: Hi Gerhard. Sorry to bear bad news, but while yes it waits now, when the file is created at the expected path, it does not react - it never attempts more actions and seems to stay in the loop. I checked the path and the file name - all good. I wonder what might be wrong still?

Comment: Gerhard - you are a star! Everything works as I'd hoped. Thank you so much for your help - and for recognising how much I needed it too! It's not fun being a newbie at this so I especially appreciate you going the extra mile. Cheers sir!